# Ignore keyboard event on waitKey() in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm learning OpenCV and I decided to make a snake game using it. It's almost done but there is a slight problem that seems simple but I couldn't find a solution.

```
while True:
    move()
    cv2.imshow('Snake Game', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(250)
```

It's supposed to wait 250 miliseconds before the next frame but key presses break the waiting so game speeds up when I hold down a key. How can I make it ignore the keyboard events and only use time?

Comment: It seems that the wait key code is inside an infinite loop, please, provide more details about your code and what you want it to do

Comment: There is a different thread where I get key input. This loop is in the main thread. It moves the snake, shows the frame, waits for 250 ms and keeps looping until I exit the program. My problem is that when I'm holding down a key it continues the loop without waiting. I tried time.sleep instead of waitKey but then imshow doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I would be very surprised if `waitKey` didn't stop the waiting after key presses. In fact the name itself suggest that. So basically it's like calling a function called max and then expect the minimum.

From your code and what you've described, you're using `waitKey` for two reasons:

1. waiting for some fixed time. That means you're using it to synchronize your game loop.
2. using it (maybe) to handle key presses for user interaction with the game.

In my opinion, first thing to do is to stop waiting and just keep showing frames continuously as soon as it is ready. And for synchronization you just need to save time for each frame printing. And using that time you update after user interaction or deciding how to process frame or ... One place to help you in that is to look at how game loops are implemented.Take a look here : https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/651/how-should-i-write-a-main-game-loop

Comment: Thank you for your time. I ended up having a waitKey(1) in the main loop and moved the move() to a new thread and used time.sleep before making moves. It works but I just wanted to know a way to display images with OpenCV for a certain time without being able to be interrupted by key presses. But it doesn't seem to be possible for some reason.